# How to do a Google search for webpages last updated within 2 years?

Tags: google-search

How to do a Google search for webpages last updated within 2 years ?

In other words I would like Google, but I do not wish any of the results to be over 2 years old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: search Google by time range]

You can search for a webpage that is indexed in Google in a particular time period by selecting the `More` option from different search options available in left side of Google page. Select the time period like last hour, last year etc. or you can enter a custom time period in which you can specify exact date range.

Comment: See also: http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=142143&rd=1

Answer (score 1):

after the search words, add something like this:

```
before:2022-11-25
```

There's before: and after:  and probably others.  I don't know of a way to give relative time, such as ten days ago, but the date as yyyy-mm-dd always works (so far).