# "Older than" Internet search filter

Tags: search-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do a Google search for webpages last updated within 2 years?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17417/how-to-do-a-google-search-for-webpages-last-updated-within-2-years)

Because the Internet has grown exponentially every year, when I search for pages posted on the Internet 10 years ago it is crowded out by similar postings of more recent origin.

Has any search engine got an "older than" filter?

Comment: Even if there was (at one time) a related solution, this is not a duplicate of [How to do a Google search for webpages last updated within 2 years?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17417/145976). For one thing, this question isn't constrained to _Google search_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Google web search **Show options** you can set a time period for your searches:

[image: google]

Specific date range:

[image: google2]

Comment: No longer possible with Google. :(