# Google search results from custom time/date range

Tags: google-search

The only option Google offers is to get results from the past hour. Is it possible to get results from the past 3 hours, for example? From the past 2 years would also be useful for me.

> **Related:**
>   [How to do a Google search for webpages last updated within 2 years?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17417/how-to-do-a-google-search-for-webpages-last-updated-within-2-years)

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks for all your great work. I wanted to point out that you made a mistake here. The OP @Gradient did not post of duplicate question. Anyone who closely reads the question will easily ascertain that what OP is asking could possibly better be put `How to filter Google search results less than > 1 hr *AND* < 24 hr. I hope you will do the right thing and unmark this as a dupe. The "accepted" answer isn't even the right answer, and the OP has objected (3 years ago) to this being marked a dupe as well. Than you.

Comment: @CodeSlayer2010 I have re-opened this question as I am inclined to agree with you. This question is about getting Google results on a per hour basis rather than per day (which is what the related question refers too) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding all google result from 2011-12-31 till 2012-12-31

- add *daterange:2455927-2456293* to your search term
- you have to update both numbers every day you wanna do the search
- [this](http://jwebnet.net/advancedgooglesearch.html#advDateRange) link helps you converting a date to a serial

You will get the same by using the custom range search option

[image]

Unfortunately you can't search for *past 2 hours* using the same method.

Comment: While this comment at least attempts to answer the poster, sadly, it distracts and confuses the issue by adding a graphic and an explanation of how to do a related, but different operation. The real answer is given as the sentence immediately following the graphic.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [this website](https://searchengineland.com/searching-google-in-past-minutes-or-seconds-25764)

Do a search, then add this to the end of what you searched for:

&tbs=qdr:X##&tbo=1

The X## portion gets replaced with:

s## for number of seconds you want to narrow your search to, such as s45 for the last 45 seconds, or &tbs=qdr:s45&tbo=1

n## for number of minutes you want to narrow your search to, such as n5 for the last 5 minutes, or &tbs=qdr:n5&tbo=1

h## for number of minutes you want to narrow your search to, such as h2 for the last 2 hours, or &tbs=qdr:h2&tbo=1

That portion gets added to the end of whatever you’ve searched for initially. For example, say you searched for [kanye west] from the Google home page. After doing your search, you’d add the examples above like this:

Past 45 seconds:
http://www.google.com/#&q=kanye+west&tbs=qdr:s45&tbo=1

Past 5 minutes
http://www.google.com/#&q=kanye+west&tbs=qdr:n5&tbo=1

Past 2 hours
http://www.google.com/#&q=kanye+west&tbs=qdr:h2&tbo=1

The time indicates when Google added the material to its index, not necessarily when it was published.