# Is there a keyword to search for Google results within the last x days/weeks/months/years?

Tags: google-search, search-operators

Is there a keyword (see [this](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en&ref_topic=3081620)) to search for results within the last *x* days/weeks/months/years?

I know that you can do this by adding code at the end of the search URL, e.g. for results dating no more than 3 months add

```
&tbs=qdr:m3
```

However, I'm looking for a keyword to do so directly in the search box.

Related but not a duplicate: [How to do a Google search for webpages last updated within 2 years?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17417/how-to-do-a-google-search-for-webpages-last-updated-within-2-years)

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 17 times.

Comment: add to the search something like: before:2022-01-15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to search within a date range, via search box with [Julian dates](http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm), which was [previously undocumented](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/google-hacks-2nd/0596008570/ch01s28.html), and which by [May 22, 2018](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/) seemed to be not officially deprecated, is not working.

So, the answer to your concise question seems to be *No, there is not*.

PS: Interesting...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-date-range/nnncnafimiibjpndjnomejlbjbpmdcmf?hl=en